# Selenium: How to find a div that hiding in <a>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to use selenium to find a div:
[image]

My code is :

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="bh-headerBar-nav-item"]').click()
```

But I got the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="bh-headerBar-nav-item"]"}
```

What should I do to find this div?

Comment: Have you applied any waits?

Comment: Any possible that the `a` and/or `div` is inside a `frame`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the style value of the element to block using javascript.

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[0].style.display = 'block';")
```

Then try to access the element.

Answer (score 0):

Short:

Your xpath looks correct for the exampled page html, but the class on screenshot ends with the space char. (it could be the reason).

Longer:

If you getting `NoSuchElementException` there can be 3 cases:

1. your div present in `iframe`, so you need to switch to iframe with `driver.switch_to.iframe` command before invoke find_element.
2. you looking for div with the exact class match. class attribute sometimes changed after some actions, some classes could be added or removed. So, try to use `//div[contains(@class, 'your_class')]`. I see, your class ends with the space char on screenshot, it may affect.
3. the element really not present on the page.
   Try to take screenshot, or print pagesource and look for the element, may be this will bring more information regarding the real reason.

Answer (score -1):

The *DIV* tag is a descendant of the *A* tag.

To click on the descendant *DIV* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#/sportVenueBookBC'] div.bh-headerBar-nav-item.").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='#/sportVenueBookBC']//div[@class='bh-headerBar-nav-item ']").click()
  ```

---

However, the desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#/sportVenueBookBC'] div.bh-headerBar-nav-item."))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='#/sportVenueBookBC']//div[@class='bh-headerBar-nav-item ']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)